# Odoo XML-RPC move stock from one storage location to another when there are multiple putaway rules for product

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc

I'm using Odoo external API to retrieve and write data in Odoo. It worked for me to use stock.move model for moving stock from one storage location to another.

Right now, l have multiple putaway rules for that product and every time when l try to move stock from one putaway rule location to another, all stock goes to only one location every time l try.

Does somebody know why all stock go to one particular location when there are multiple putaway rules?

```
 self.object_proxy.execute_kw(settings.ODOO_DB, self.uid, settings.ODOO_PASSWORD,
                                 'stock.move', 'create',
                                 [{
                                     'product_id': product_id,
                                     'product_uom': 1,  
                                     'product_uom_qty': 0,  
                                     'location_id': location_id,
                                     'location_dest_id': location_dest_id,
                                     'quantity_done': quantity,
                                     'state': 'done'
                                 }])
```

Comment: Can you share some code ?, perhaps the problem is that something is missing using the API but not using the form directly (assuming it works in the normal way).

Comment: @Alonso So, l have 3 putaway rules and let's say that putaway rule No. 2 is "main" rule. Whenever l try to move stock from location 1 (putaway rule 1) to location 3, every time this quantity goes to location 2, which belongs to ''main'' putaway rule 2. So l do not see solution how to change stock between two locations in one warehouse when putaway rule exists.